# HTML/CSS Horizontal sub-submenu attached to vertical submenu

Tags: html, css, menu, submenu

I am wanting to align a vertical sub-submenu that is horizontal to a submenu, like this: [image]

I am able to achieve this, as the picture shows, but I have to make the position absolute. The problem with that is I would want the top part of each sub-submenu to line up with the top of the submenu it is attached too. For instance, the artist sub-submenu would be exactly the same as the one shown, but would have A to Z lined up with Artist.

In order to do that the way I am doing it now, I would have to create many different css sections, rather than being able to select multiple submenus with one section (for instance #sortsongmenu, #sortartistmenu { styling }. I would like to find a way to have the sub-submenus in the position shown without having to position each sub-submenu separately, but rather have a styling approach that could apply to all sub-submenus that have relative or some other positioning.

HTML code:

```css
<-- CSS code--> 
#topbar {
background-color: #222;
}
#topbar_wrapper {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
}





#mainmenu {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
position: relative;
min-width: 200px;
}
#mainmenu li {
display: inline-block;
width: 200px;
}
#mainmenu li:hover {
background-color: #333;
}
#mainmenu li a{
color: #CCC;
display: block;
padding: 15px;
text-decoration: none;
}
#mainmenu li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}





#sortmenu {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #333;
border: 5px solid #222;
border-top: 0;
margin-left: -5px;
}
#sortmenu li {
display: block;
}
#sortmenu li a:hover {
color: #699;
}
#sortmenu li: hover ul {
display: inline-block;
}





#sortsongmenu, #sortartistmenu {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #333;
border: 5px solid #222;
border-left: 0px;
text-align: right;
left: 100%;
bottom: 65%;
width: 100px;
}

#sortsongmenu li, #sortartistmenu li{
display: inline;
}

#sortsongmenu li a:hover, #sortartistmenu li a:hover {
color: #DB7093;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  <div id="topbar_wrapper">
    <ul id="mainmenu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Search</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Sort By &#9660</a>
        <ul id="sortmenu">
          <li><a href='#'>Song</a>
            <ul id="sortsongmenu">
              <li><a href='#'>A to Z</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='#'>Z to A</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href='#'>Artist</a>
            <ul id="sortartistmenu">
              <li><a href='#'>A to Z</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='#'>Z to A</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href='#'>Album</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href='#'>Genre</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href='#'>BPM</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href='#'>Release Date</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Add Song</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Contant Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you give the rest of a code in a fiddle because right now it looks like this which is no good for anything http://jsfiddle.net/3fhgfbb2/

Comment: I have placed your code into a snippet, and there is definitely not enough information for us to reproduce your menu.

Comment: yes, just one second...

Comment: top code is css, bottom code is html. had trouble with reformatting, which is why they are mislabeled...

Comment: If you're interested, I built [this example from scratch](https://jsbin.com/xayeti/edit?css,output). Might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

Change

```
#sortmenu li {
    display: block;
}

#sortsongmenu, #sortartistmenu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #333;
    border: 5px solid #222;
    border-left: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    left: 100%;
    bottom: 65%;
    width: 100px;
}
```

to

```
#sortmenu > li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

#sortsongmenu, #sortartistmenu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #333;
    border: 5px solid #222;
    border-left: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

EDITED:

Change top to -5px, as your sub submenu have a border top of 5px. It will look better that way.

Comment: that seems to be working. I just had to readjust my absolute positioning, but other than that it worked like a charm. Much thanks!